# Multi valued attributes in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have designed a send message system in which users can send a message to more than one person at a time. so the recipient attribute of a message is multi valued. so i designed an other table called message_recipients.

Here are my tables:

```
create table `message`(
`message_id`           INT(11)      NOT NULL primary key auto_increment,
`sender`               VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL,
`topic`                VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`content`              TEXT         NOT NULL,
`message_date`         TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL  ,
`readed`               VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`deleted_by_sender`    VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`deleted_by_recipient` VARCHAR(1)   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(sender)    REFERENCES   users(user_name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


create table `message_recipients`(
`message_id` INT         NOT NULL ,
`recipient`  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY(message_id,recipient),
FOREIGN KEY(message_id) REFERENCES message(message_id) on delete cascade,
FOREIGN KEY(recipient)  REFERENCES users(user_name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

When i insert a message in `message` table i need to get its `message_id` and insert it with recipient or recipients into `message_recipients` table.

Here is my script:

```
insert into `message`(`sender`,`topic`,`content`)
values('me','need help','how to get last inserted row');
select message_id from `message` order by `message_id` desc limit 0,1;
```

When i got the `message_id`, i can now insert it into `message_recipients` with some users as recipient, and now question is that; is there any better or more optimized way?

Comment: Don't use `varchar` for a flag field. Use `bit` or `tinyint` depending on your version. You may also want to use an `unsigned` id column

Answer (score 1):

Use the function mysql_insert_id() instead of

```
select message_id from `message` order by `message_id` limit 0,1;
```

This is a built-in MySQL method that will get you the just inserted primary key.  The SELECT statement above might not be reliable if there are a large number of simultaneous inserts.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that they'll get the **correct** last `message_id` in that session.

Comment: :) you copied my script :) ok what should i do? is there any better way?

Comment: If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html